# jQuery disable only one option in a radiobutton list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a radiobutton list that is rendered as

```
<input id="rblOD_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblOD" value="1">
<input id="rblOD_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblOD" value="2">
<input id="rblOD_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblOD" value="3">
```

I want to disable the last item only on page load and enable it after doing checks from the db. I am doing this to do it

```
$("input:radio[name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblOD'][value='3']")
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

It doesn't work on load but it works in the radiobuttonlist change event. How can I get it to work on load or without any click or change events?

Comment: Does the page actually render like that and are you doing `$(function() {
  $("input:radio[name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblOD'][value='3']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});`

Comment: 1) is your code within document.ready (see [learn.jquery.com](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)) *or* appearing after your `inputs`?

Comment: It is rendered as an HTML table with TR and TD tags. Each option is in a separate TR tag. And I am calling a function in the $(document).ready(function () { DisableRadio(); }

Comment: 2) are your inputs generated *dynamically* - ie after the page has finished loading (without the inputs) then load the inputs via ajax or similar

Comment: they are not dynamic. It's defined as a static asp:radiobuttonlist control

Comment: Then you'll need to provide a complete snippet that demonstrates the issue (see [mcve]) as it's trivial to show that the code you've provided, *as provided*, works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/shy9nbum/

Comment: PS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder has a lowercase `h`

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan better tell Microsoft, not much we can do about it inside an MS wrapper: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder?view=netframework-4.8.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is actually working now. The reason it wasn't working was because in the code-behind there was a script that was being called in the pageload that was re-enabling the radiobutton item.

`$("input:radio[name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblOD'][value='3']") .attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

This is the working code

Thanks